# Is there a HTML Widget library in TT2?

Tags: perl, templates, toolkit

I'm writing an app with Catalyst + TT2.  It seems like it'd be nice to have a UI Widget library for rendering some of the HTML.  I.e. Tables and Drop downs and such would be much nicer if I just called a function, passed in a hash of options, and a list of data.

Was wondering if there was something like that.  Or if I should look into something else with Catalyst to do the HTML rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that YAHOO UI is what you need.

Comment: That's a front-end JS Gui toolkit isn't it?  I was really wondering if there were HTML Widget libraries that send HTML from the server.  I know of EXT.js and others that do similar things too.  but again that's all client side.

Comment: Yes its a front-end gui toolkit.However once you use catalyst and template toolkit you should not have this kind of problem.
Put html code in a template and add your data in stash through your controller.Then just forward to this template.

Comment: Suppose I have a more-complex HTML generation I'm reusing.  Maybe something like a HTML Table that has extra HTML decorating parts of it that I want to reuse.  And what if I'm using it 2-3 times in a page?  Well then stash wouldn't work right?  I'd need pass data around to it.  Does catalyst break down in usefulness when you get more complex?  I hope not.